# Matching two columns of two tables for a particular value in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

Consider there are two tables:
TABLE1 and TABLE2 ,Both of them have same attributes i.e. ID,NAME,CLASS,STATUS.
These two tables has data for all the students in the school...but managed by two independent bodies.

On the basis of unique ID I want to check that for all the students whether the data is same in both the tables.

I would be interested in retrieving the unmatched data in both tables, But don't want the unmatched data where status of a student is 'lefttheschool' in both the tables(and if status is 'lefttheschool'in one table and'present'in other ,it is unmatched and it should  be retrieved).

For example:

```
          TABLE1 ID NAME CLASS STATUS 
               1   A     3    PRESENT
               2   B     4    LEFT
               3   B     7    LEFT

        TABLE2 ID NAME CLASS STATUS 
               1   A     3    PRESENT
               2   C     4    PRESENT
               3   B     5    LEFT

        RESULT:ID NAME CLASS STATUS       ID NAME CLASS STATUS

               2   B     4    LEFT        2   C     4    PRESENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all when ID is the same and other attribute is different:

```
select table1.*, table2.*
  from table1, table2
 where table1.id = table2.id
   and ( table1.name <> table2.name or
       table1.class <> table2.class or table1.status <> table2.status)
   and (table1.status <>'LEFT' and table2.status <>'LEFT')
```

Comment: Thanks!But I don't want to retrieve those records where status is left both sides.!!!!

Comment: add check for not LEFT in both

Comment: how...thats the real question?

Comment: I updated my answer, I added a check for not LEFT in both

Comment: WIll it work in case ,status is left one side ...and present at other...It should i guess!